# Joomla: Second external javascript file accessing variables from the first external javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, external

I hope the title is not very confusing. I've got the following scenario.

Please keep in mind that this is a question related to **Joomla**.

I have two external JavaScript files: **accordion.js** and **initialize.js** which I include in the **index.php** file of my template.

**accordion.js** looks like this:

```
function Accordion ( options ) {
    /* code here */
}
Accordion.prototype.someFunction = function ( params ) {
      /* code here that uses JQuery */
}
```

This however won't work because of JQuery no conflict. One must do the following:

```
(function($) {

    function Accordion ( options ) {
        /* code here */
    }
    Accordion.prototype.someFunction = function ( params ) {
       /* code here that uses JQuery */
    }

})(JQuery)
```

And it does work. If I type an alert('Hello') in that block, it works.

Now I have an external file **initialize.js** that was also included into the template.

This file needs to be able to access (and instantiate) the class Accordion. So it looks like this:

```
(function($) {
     $(document).ready(function() {
        var accordion =  new Accordion({});
        /* other code here that uses JQuery */
     });
}
```

Here, Javascript says that it does not know what "Accordion" is.

If I move this piece of code, however, into the accordion.js file, it will work.

```
(function($) {

    function Accordion ( options ) {
        /* code here */
    }
    Accordion.prototype.someFunction = function ( params ) {
       /* code here that uses JQuery */
    }

     $(document).ready(function() {
        var accordion =  new Accordion({});
        /* other code here that uses JQuery */
     });
})(JQuery)
```

This works.

I believe I understand why it doesn't work. This has to do with scope, right? These two files are basically two different (en)closed blocks that cannot access each other.

My question is now, how do I enable them to communicate? How do I make the script in **accordion.js** global, so that **initialize.js** can access its variables and functions?

PS: Let us pretend there is no other way, but to separate the script and its initialisation into two different files. You include the **accordion.js** script and it's initialization **initialize.js**. I know there may be better ways of doing this, but I am not allowed to change the HTML Code in order to make the initialization more generic / global and work with only one file.